# Ajax detect when from submit is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I'm trying to figure out when my node server responds to my ajax submit. Currently the form sends over a few strings to the server where it finds the file and sends it back to the client. I want to be able to detect when the client receives the file so I can change the webpage. I've tried to use Ajax Form but I don't think it supports receiving files, only XML or JSON responses etc. When I tried it the node server would do the right thing and send the file but the client would never receive it. Here is my current code that works and the client receives the file but I wan't to be able to change the webpage once they receive it which it does not.

```
  $(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
     var form = $(this).parents().find("#download-form").submit();
     $(this).addClass("disabled");
     $(this).html("<i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin'></i>");
  });
```

Comment: `.submit()` will reload the page isn't it ?

Comment: Do you want to listen `window.onload` event ?

Comment: Why not make ajax call and get the link to the file? On success callback of ajax you can change the webpage content.
Is it necessary to send the file data in the response? Usually it is not a good practice as it takes more bandwidth.

Comment: Hmmm maybe @RayonDabre all I want to really do once the file is received is to remove the "disable" class from a element. So if I can do that sure, just that there are many download forms and buttons on the webpage so I'm not sure if I would be able to find the one that the file is referencing.

Comment: I can't do that since the file is made up from user inputs so I'd much rather send it directly to them upload it and then redirect them elsewhere @rajesh

Answer (score 0):

You can set form's `target` attribute to an iframe and add an event listener to the iframe's `load` event.

Example: (also in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1pzfu0h3/1/))

```
<script>
     document.getElementById("resultFrame").addEventListener("load", function(){
        // do something once iframe loaded
        document.getElementById("resultCount").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("resultCount").textContent)+1;
    });
</script>

<form method="GET" action="https://fiddle.jshell.net/img/logo.png" target="resultFrame">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<p id="resultCount">0</p>

<iframe name="resultFrame" id="resultFrame"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ajax:complete` event to detect success of your form submit()

```
var form = $(this).parents().find("#download-form");
form.bind('ajax:complete', function() {
         // tasks to do 
});
form.submit();
```